# Link not clickable in Wordpress Menu but can be opened in a new tab

Tags: php, css, wordpress

**Disclaimer:** I am sorry the post looks too big but I just thought I should provide all the details. I am sure the issue is something very stupid but I am not able to figure out :(

**Background:** I am creating a wordpress site using an awesome theme called Parallax from Access Press. I wanted to play out my business website before buying the pro version so decided to make a few changes myself.

**Problem:** You can either use the theme's menu (which allows animation and same page scroll; This Golum wantses) or use native wordpress menus (which does not allow scrolling; Golum hateses).

**Workaround Tried:** I figured I can go into the header.php and add one menu item manually. So following is the code per my understanding:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        <div class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'accesspress_parallax' ); ?></div>

            <?php 
            $sections = of_get_option('parallax_section');
            if(of_get_option('enable_parallax') == 1 && of_get_option('enable_parallax_nav') == 1):
            ?>
            <ul class="nav single-page-nav">
                <?php
                $home_text = of_get_option('home_text');
                if(of_get_option('show_slider')== "yes" && !empty($home_text)) : ?>
                    <li class="current"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>#main-slider"><?php echo esc_attr($home_text); ?></a></li>

                <?php endif;

                if(!empty($sections)):
                foreach ($sections as $single_sections): 
                    if($single_sections['layout'] != "action_template" && $single_sections['layout'] != "blank_template" && $single_sections['layout'] != "googlemap_template" && !empty($single_sections['page'])) :
                    $title = get_the_title($single_sections['page']); ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>#section-<?php echo $single_sections['page']; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>
                    <?php 
                    endif;
                endforeach; 
                endif; ?>
                    <li><a href="http://google.com" target="_self">Pre-order Here</a></li>
            </ul>
            <?php   
            else: 
                <some more code that picks custom menu if you choose to skip parallax menu>

        </nav>
```

The first LI item just puts the text 'Home' in the page. Second one picks all the values from parallax menu. **The Last LI item is the one I have included.**

```
                <li><a href="http://google.com" target="_self">Pre-order Here</a></li>
```

**Behavior:** This perfectly adds the item to the menu and also appears to be clickable. The problem is - when it is clicked, it does nothing. If I right click it and open in a new tab, it works perfectly fine. Including related CSS below for your reference

**Edit:** If I include a link to another section of the page. it works. Example: http://domain.com/#section-20

```
.main-navigation {
    float: right;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.logo-top .main-navigation{
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: none;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main-navigation ul li{
    position: relative;
}
.main-navigation > ul > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;  
    font-weight: 400;
}
.main-navigation > ul > li > a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:14px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
.main-navigation > ul > li.current a{
    color: #E66432;
}
.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#333;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left:0;
    z-index: 99999;
    padding:0 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
    min-width: 200px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    padding: 8px 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li:last-child{
    border:none;
}
.main-navigation li:hover > a {
    color: #E66432;
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a {
    color: #E66432;
```

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong, there might be some JS doing something to your links? Try removing `target="_self"`, you should not need it.

Comment: Was experimenting with target="_blank" but doesn't work. No changes even if I remove that.

Any clue where should I start looking for JS? I am a non-tech by background but can figure out codes if I put enough time.

Comment: Edit: If I include a link to another section of the page, it works. Example: http://domain.com/#section-20

Comment: Still sounds like a JS issue. First try to disable all of your plugins, if the problem still persists, then you know it must be something in the theme. If so, try searching for the menu IDs and see if anything pops up. The JS could be anywhere really. Also check if there are any JS errors in your console.

Comment: It could be that the class, or the id that you put, are targeted in the JS code and have prevented default behavior, which means that even if you click on a link, it won't do a thing. Usually a menu is created with a [walker function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) in wordpres, so instead of just pasting the links yourself, you should try using the functions that are meant to handle the menus in wordpress.

Comment: Also, from what I've seen they are using [this](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) plugin to control the page navigation scrolling. This could also prevent the default behavior of the menu (scroll to section vs go to page).

Comment: Thanks @pschueller 

1. Disable Plugins. No change. 
2. Checked console. There is the following error but I don't think it is related

Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources. SecurityError

3. Will follow with a comment on JS short based on what dingo_d posted

Comment: Thanks @dingo_d

Found the JS file but can't make much out of it. Looking at JS for the first time but will try to figure out. I also tried to breakout the <li> item in a different <ul> without a class. The link works fine in that case but the formatting is all messed up. Any chance CSS is messing with it?

Comment: well if you changed the structure of the html, the css won't match it so it will be messed up. You'll need to redo the css. Or disable the OnePageNav plugin. This will revert the menu to simple click and go menu (should in theory).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @pschueller and @dingo_d!!

You pushed me into the correct direction. The github to the JS plugin for scroll has the secret sauce.

I had to add a class='external' to my  tag with the href and update the jquery.nav.js with the following:

Replaced

```
filter: '',
```

with

```
filter: ':not(.external)',
```